# C# adding data to SQL database

Tags: c#, sql

Background: 
I am trying to add data to a SQL DB with C#. I am currently doing so in my script in another class so im using the same code (the code works). However, my current class is using a bunch of recycled code and i am having issues narrowing down why i can not write to the DB. Below is the code i am using and it is broken down to the bare bones minimum code.

What I'm asking for:
anyone to point out some dumb mistake i made or ideas where to troubleshoot. Currently i am just staring at this code and cant see whats wrong.

Thanks in advance!

```
public void AddAttachmentToDB(XmlNode root, XmlNamespaceManager xmlns, string  MessageID, string MailBoxAliasName)
{
    //open DB
    #region Open DB
    if (DbConnection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        try
        {
            this.DbConnection.ConnectionString = DbConnectionString;
            this.DbConnection.Open();
            MailboxListener._logging.LogWrite("[{0}] opened DB Connection in AddAttachmentToDB!",
                LoggingLevels.Error,
                System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ToString(),
                this.DbConnectionString);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MailboxListener._logging.LogWrite("[{0}] Failed to open DB Connection! For Machine: {1}",
                 LoggingLevels.Error,
                 System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ToString(),
                 this.DbConnectionString);
            MailboxListener._logging.LogWrite("[{0}] Error Returned: {1}",
                LoggingLevels.Error,
                System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ToString(),
                ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MailboxListener._logging.LogWrite("[{0}] Failed to open DB Connection in AddAttachmentToDB!",
                 LoggingLevels.Error,
                 System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ToString(),
                 this.DbConnectionString);
    }
            #endregion
    //once db is open try this
    try
    {
        //create test variables       
        string strMailBoxAliasName = MailBoxAliasName;
        string AttachmentFilename = string.Empty;
        string strfiletype = string.Empty;
        string AttachmentStream = string.Empty;
        string strAttachmentID = string.Empty;
        string strMessageID = string.Empty;
        strMessageID = MessageID;

        //fill test variables
        AttachmentFilename = "yumyum";
        AttachmentStream = "Cheetos";
        strMessageID = "123";
        strMailBoxAliasName = "user";
        strfiletype = ".txt";
        strAttachmentID = "12345";

        //create sql insert string
        String insString = @"INSERT INTO MailboxListenerAttachments Values (@attachmentfilename, @attachmentbody,
        @messageID, @mailboxname, @filetype, @attachmentID, @DateAddedToDB)";

        //create sql command string
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(insString, this.DbConnection);

        //add fill test variables to sql insert string
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@attachmentfilename", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
        myCommand.Parameters["@attachmentfilename"].Value = AttachmentFilename;
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@attachmentbody", SqlDbType.VarChar, 8000);
        myCommand.Parameters["@attachmentbody"].Value = AttachmentStream.Trim();
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@messageID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500);
        myCommand.Parameters["@messageID"].Value = strMessageID;
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@mailboxname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
        myCommand.Parameters["@mailboxname"].Value = strMailBoxAliasName;
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@filetype", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        myCommand.Parameters["@filetype"].Value = strfiletype;
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@attachmentID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        myCommand.Parameters["@attachmentID"].Value = strAttachmentID;
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@DateAddedToDB", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            myCommand.Parameters["@DateAddedToDB"].Value = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();

        //run sql command
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //log sql command events
        MailboxListener._logging.LogWrite(
                "[{0}] Added attachment {1} to database for messageID: {2}",
                LoggingLevels.Informational,
                System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ToString(),
                AttachmentFilename,
                strMessageID
            );
        //if DB is open, close it
        if (DbConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            this.DbConnection.Close();
        }
    }
    //catch errors 
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MailboxListener._logging.LogWrite("[{0}] Error Returned: {1}",
                LoggingLevels.Error,
                System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ToString(),
                ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is an error reported?  Knowing the error message would help.

Comment: Do you get an exception?

Comment: no errors and no exceptions given. That's why im at a loss. I know the code is running all the way through because the other class writes to the DB.

Comment: Just small tip, move the `//if DB is open, close it` section to `finally` block otherwise you'll end up with zombie open connections when there are exceptions..

Comment: Please specify what are the exceptions that your code throws. Check also if something happens inside the `try-catch` statements, it sounds like an hidden exception.

Comment: @shadow Wizard: are you sure? Will my try statement work without an open DB connection?

Comment: @toosweet That's not what I said. What I mean that normally the `Close()` method of the connection will be called fine. But when there is exception, it won't be called.

Comment: Also, try removing the `try..catch` and see if you get "real" error now. Maybe logger is not working properly.

Comment: Have you tried the SQL query in SQL server? Try to execute it there and check if it's adding the information well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea why this doesn't work but this code screams for refactoring:

```
public void AddAttachmentToDB(
    XmlNode root, 
    XmlNamespaceManager xmlns, 
    string MessageID, 
    string MailBoxAliasName
)
{
    var strMailBoxAliasName = MailBoxAliasName;
    var AttachmentFilename = "yumyum";
    var AttachmentStream = "Cheetos";
    var strMessageID = "123";
    var strMailBoxAliasName = "user";
    var strfiletype = ".txt";
    var strAttachmentID = "12345";

    // Use DateTime when working with dates
    var dates123 = new DateTime(2011, 2, 3);

    try
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(DbConnectionString))
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO MailboxListenerAttachments Values (@attachmentfilename, @attachmentbody, @messageID, @mailboxname, @filetype, @attachmentID, @DateAddedToDB";

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@attachmentfilename", AttachmentFilename);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@attachmentbody", AttachmentStream.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@messageID", strMessageID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mailboxname", strMailBoxAliasName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filetype", strfiletype);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@attachmentID", strAttachmentID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateAddedToDB", dates123);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // TODO: Log the exception and propagate it
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Darin. Im going to try this re-factoring in a few minutes

Comment: Just a quick note for everyone who is using this answer as a base - there should be a closing parenthesis at the end of the "INSERT INTO" command string.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't Dates123 be of a DateTime type instead of a string?

Comment: ya that was my mistake, trying to sanitize the code. im changing that now.

Comment: The value you've provided is still a string and it should be a DateTime.  Remove ToString.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify input/output directions for all of the paramters. 
for example : `myCommand.Parameters["@attachmentfilename"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input`

Answer (score 0):

If you really have no idea you can try

1. Fix your insert statement so it
   explicitly names columns maybe your
   ordering is incorrect and insert
   statement doesnt work
2. your setting parameters length to
   maximum column length values, maybe you
   need to set them to actual parameter
   values length
3. I really think that Dates123 is
   indeed the most important problem here, it
   should be DateTime not string.

So you changed it but you still call DateTime.UtcNow.ToString() , leave it as DateTime type not string.

Comment: sorry dates123 was my mistake sanitizing my code. i changed it